# Accessing fields of a struct for a double linked list

Tags: c, list, dynamic, dynamic-allocation

I want to make a double linked list and I have a problem with accessing fields in the struct. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int val;
    struct node * next;
    struct node * prev;
}node;

void insert(int val, node **head)
{
    node * temp= *head;
    node * temp2=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    node * temp3=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp2->val=val;
    temp2->prev=NULL;
    temp2->next=*head;
    *head=temp2;
    temp2->next->prev=temp2;
}

void print(node* head)
{
    node* temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", temp->val);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{   node * head=NULL;
    insert(1, &head);
    insert(2, &head);
    print(head);
    return 0;
}
```

I get a crash at `temp2->next->prev`, and I don't understand why. Am I not allowed to access the prev field of the `temp2->next` node? I tried writing `(temp2->next)->prev` but also doesn't work. Is there any way that I cant make that work?

Comment: If you get a crash, that means usually that a pointer that you try to derefenece with `*` or `->` is either `NULL` or uninitialised. So check `temp2` and `temp2->next`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you insert the first node, `*head`, and therefore `temp->next`, is `NULL`. Check that case:

```
void insert(int val, node **head)
{
    node *temp= malloc(sizeof(*temp));

    temp->val = val;
    temp->prev = NULL;
    temp->next = *head;
    *head = temp;

    if (temp->next) temp->next->prev = temp;
}
```

(I've removed the unused variables and lost the cast on `malloc`.)

A doubly linked list should probably have a tail, too. In that case, update the tail when you append an item at the head of an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
void insert(int val, node **head)
{
    if(*head == NULL){
        node * temp2=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp2->val=val;
        *head = temp2;
    }
    else{
       node * temp= *head;
       node * temp2=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
       temp2->val=val;
       temp2->prev=NULL;
       temp2->next=temp;
       temp->prev = temp2;
    }

}
```

Most likely head was not initialized

Answer (score 0):

As I have understood you always insert a new node before the head though in double linked list you have to add new nodes usually at the tail of the list. As a double linked list usually have two sides then there is a sense to define two functions: `push_front` and `push_back`. Your function `insert` corresponds to function `push_front`.

Nevertheless function `insert` could look the following way

```
void insert( int val, node **head )
{
    node *temp = ( node * )malloc( sizeof( node ) );

    temp->val  = val;
    temp->prev = NULL;
    temp->next = *head;

    if ( *head ) ( *head )->prev = temp; 

    *head = temp;
}
```

It would be better if you would define one more structure named as for example `List` (or whatever) and that could be defined as

```
struct List
{
   node *head;
   node *tail;
};
```

Also you could add one more data member - a count of the nodes in the list, For example

```
struct List
{
   node *head;
   node *tail;
   size_t count; 
};
```

Also do not forget to write a function that would delete all nodes of the list when it is not needed any more.